Parallelizing web scraping in Python with concurrent.futures
Follow up to my question here, per @Tripleee's edit.
I have used @EuanG's suggestion, and tried the concurrent.futures library to parallelize the code. Here is my updated code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import compress
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait



def get_driver(headless):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if headless:
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    # initialize driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH,options=options)
    #driver.get(URL)
    return driver
   
def browserSettings(browser):
    base_url = "https://sisab.saude.gov.br/paginas/acessoRestrito/relatorio/federal/saude/RelSauProducao.xhtml"
    #time.sleep(3)
    browser.get(base_url)
    # Set type of service - Individual
    browser.find_element(By.ID,"tpProducao").send_keys('Atendimento Individual')

    # Set column to month (Competencia)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="selectLinha"]/optgroup[1]/option[6]').click()

    # Set Type of team
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/label/input').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a/label/input').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]/ul/li[9]/a/label/input').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[1]').click()

    # Set place of service
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/button').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/ul/li[2]/a/label/input').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosLocalTipoEstabelecimento"]/div/button').click()

    # Set type of service - Individual
    browser.find_element(By.ID,"tpProducao").send_keys('Atendimento Individual')

    # Set type of attendance - select all
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/button/span').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/ul/li[1]/a/label').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="divTipoAtendimento"]/div/button/span').click()

    # Set type of professional
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/button/span').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/a/label').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/ul/li[19]/a/label').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtroEquipeProf"]/div[2]/button/span').click()

    # Select 'years' button for age
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tpIdade:2"]').click()

And updated functions:
def setDxCode(code, codeType,browser):
    if codeType == 'CID':
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-1"]'.format(code)
        #code = code
    else:
        codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}-4"]'.format(code)
    #codeXpath = '//*[@id="cid-{}"]'.format(code)
    #codeXpath = createXpathPattern(code = code, codeType = codeType)
    browser.find_element(By.ID,"btnAddCid").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    searchBox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dtBasicExample_filter"]/label/input')
    searchBox.clear()
    searchBox.send_keys(code)
    #time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,codeXpath).click()
    searchBox.clear()
    #time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="modal-default-cid"]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]/span').click()
    
# function to set age group and sex
def setAgeLimit(agelower, ageupper,browser):
    
    """Selects the upper and lower age limit in years, and the sex for which data is to be output"""
    
    #Set lower age limit
    agelim1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idadeInicio"]')
    agelim1.clear()
    agelim1.send_keys(str(agelower))
    
    #Set uper age limit
    agelim2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="idadeFim"]')
    agelim2.clear()
    agelim2.send_keys(str(ageupper))
    
def setSex(browser,sex = 1):
    # Set Sex
    sexXpath = '//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label'.format(sex)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button/span').click() #//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,sexXpath).click() # //*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/ul/li[2]/a/label/input
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtrosCaracteristicaUsuario"]/div/button/span').click()
    
# Get list of all months in the months column in the webpage
#monthBoxes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#competencia > div > ul > li > a> label > input")
#yearMonth = []
#for i in range(len(monthBoxes)):
#    yearMonth.append(monthBoxes[i].get_attribute("value"))

def GetYearMonth(browser):
    monthBoxes = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#competencia > div > ul > li > a> label > input")
    yearMonth = []
    for i in range(len(monthBoxes)):
        yearMonth.append(monthBoxes[i].get_attribute("value"))
    return(yearMonth)

def getMonthsforYear(year,browser):
    yearMonth = GetYearMonth(browser = browser)
    year = str(year)
    boolMonth = [year in i for i in yearMonth]
    return(list(compress(yearMonth,boolMonth)))

def ClickMonthCheckbox(monthsList,browser):
    yearMonth = GetYearMonth(browser = browser)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    for month in monthsList:
        monthIdx = str(yearMonth.index(month) + 1)
        monthxpath = '//*[@id="competencia"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label/input'.format(monthIdx)
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH,monthxpath).click()

def SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year,browser):
    TmpMonthsList = getMonthsforYear(year, browser = browser)
    ClickMonthCheckbox(TmpMonthsList, browser = browser)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    
def checkboxIsSelected(monthsList,browser):
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    for month in monthsList:
        monthIdx = str(yearMonth.index(month) + 1)
        monthxpath = '//*[@id="competencia"]/div/ul/li[{}]/a/label/input'.format(monthIdx)
        checkbox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,monthxpath)
        print(checkbox.is_selected())

def checkboxYearIsSelected(year,browser):
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    TmpMonthsList = getMonthsforYear(year)
    checkboxIsSelected(TmpMonthsList)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="competencia"]/div/button/span').click()
    
def getHTMLtable(browser):
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="j_idt44"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/label').click() # Click on submit button
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tabela_length"]/label/select').send_keys('100') # Set number of rows in table to 100
    t = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tabela"]').get_attribute('outerHTML') # //*[@id="tabela"]/tbody
    table = pd.read_html(t,thousands ='.')
    table_dt = pd.concat(table)
    #table_dt['sex'] = 'Female'
    #table_dt['agelower'] = 5
    #table_dt['ageupper'] = 9
    return(table_dt)

def SetParametersAndGetTable(agemin,agemax,sex,year, code, codeType,browser):
    if sex == 1:
        sexL = "Both sexes"
    elif sex == 2:
        sexL = "Males"
    else:
        sexL = "Females"
    
    dlCode = code + "." + str(year) + "." + sexL + "." + str(agemin) + "." + str(agemax)
    
    setAgeLimit(agelower = agemin,ageupper = agemax,browser = browser)
    SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year,browser = browser)
    setSex(sex = sex,browser = browser)
    setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType,browser = browser)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        table_dt = getHTMLtable(browser = browser)
        table_dt['code'] = code
        table_dt['sex'] = sexL
        table_dt['agelower'] = agemin
        table_dt['ageupper'] = agemax
        table_dt = table_dt[['code','sex', 'agelower', 'ageupper','Competência','Atendimento Individual']]
        table_dt.rename(columns = {'Competência':"YearMonth",'Atendimento Individual':"individual.visits", 
                               'code':'code','sex':"sex",'agelower':"agelower",'ageupper':"ageupper"},inplace= True)
        table_dt['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(table_dt['YearMonth'], format = "%Y%m").dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
        setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType,browser = browser) # Unselect code
        time.sleep(1)
        setSex(sex = sex,browser = browser) # Unselect Sex 
        SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year,browser = browser) # Unselect yearMonth parameters
        return(table_dt)
    except:
        print(f'Table not found for {dlCode}')
        setDxCode(code = code, codeType = codeType,browser = browser) # Unselect code
        time.sleep(1)
        setSex(sex = sex,browser = browser) # Unselect Sex 
        SelectAllMonthsInaYear(year,browser = browser) # Unselect yearMonth parameters

def getVarsFromDF(df,rownum):
    year = df.loc[rownum,'year']
    sex = df.loc[rownum,'sex']
    agelower = df.loc[rownum,'agelower']
    ageupper = df.loc[rownum,'ageupper']
    code = df.loc[rownum,'code']
    codeType = df.loc[rownum,'codeType']
    
    if sex == 1:
        sexL = "Both sexes"
    elif sex == 2:
        sexL = "Males"
    else:
        sexL = "Females"
    
    anx_dep_key = code + "." + str(year) + "." + str(sex) + "." + str(agelower) + "." + str(ageupper)
    #print(anx_dep_key)
    table_name = "~/sisab/data/anxiety_depression_with_codes/parallel_download/sisab_anx_dep_code_{}_{}_{}_{}_to_{}.xlsx".format(code,str(year),sexL,str(agelower),str(ageupper))
    #print(table_name)
    return({'year':year,'sex':sex,'sexL':sexL,'ageupper':ageupper,'agelower':agelower,'code':code,'codeType':codeType,'anx_dep_key':anx_dep_key,'table_name':table_name})
        
def getRowArgs(df,rownum,browser):
    year = df.loc[rownum,'year']
    sex = df.loc[rownum,'sex']
    agelower = df.loc[rownum,'agelower']
    ageupper = df.loc[rownum,'ageupper']
    code = df.loc[rownum,'code']
    codeType = df.loc[rownum,'codeType']
    
    if sex == 1:
        sexL = "Both sexes"
    elif sex == 2:
        sexL = "Males"
    else:
        sexL = "Females"
    
    anx_dep_key = code + "." + str(year) + "." + str(sex) + "." + str(agelower) + "." + str(ageupper)
    print(anx_dep_key)
    table_name = "~/sisab/data/anxiety_depression_with_codes/parallel_download/sisab_anx_dep_code_{}_{}_{}_{}_to_{}.xlsx".format(code,str(year),sexL,str(agelower),str(ageupper))
    print(table_name)
    
    try:
        print("Scraping code {}, year {}, for {} in age range {} to {}".format(code,str(year),sexL,str(agelower),str(ageupper)))
    
        table_dt = SetParametersAndGetTable(agemin = agelower,agemax = ageupper,sex = sex,year = year, code = code, codeType = codeType,browser = browser)
        table_dt.to_excel(table_name,index = False,header = True)
        Anx_Dep_dict[anx_dep_key] = table_dt
        return(table_dt)
    except:
        notRun = {'Code':code,'codeType':codeType,'Year':year,'Sex':sex,'agelower':agelower,'ageupper':ageupper}
        noRun.append(notRun)
        
def run_process(headless,df, number):
    Browser = get_driver(headless = False)
    browserSettings(browser = Browser)
    #vars = getVarsFromDF(df = combns, rownum = 365)
    #setSex(browser = Browser,sex = vars['sex'])
    #test_dt = SetParametersAndGetTable(browser = Browser,agemin = vars['agelower'],agemax = vars['ageupper'],sex = vars['sex'],year = vars['year'], code = vars['code'], 
    #                         codeType = vars['codeType'])

    table_dt = getRowArgs(df = df, rownum = number,browser = Browser)
    Browser.close()
    return(table_dt)

Finally, run the code in multiple threads:
noRun = []
Anx_Dep_dict = {}
futures = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # scrape and crawl
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3) as executor:
        for number in range(0,combns.shape[0]):
            futures.append(
                executor.submit(run_process, headless = True, df = combns, number = number)
            )

wait(futures)

While this seems to work well, I am running into the issue of some rows being missed out, at random seemingly. I am not sure how to fix or diagnose this issue. Any recommendations?

sometimes it is good to check HTML structure to troubleshoot problems... I'd went through similiar issue but problem was on Web's HTML structure. Did u check Web's HTML structure??
